# How the code is executed in this complete query

Tags: sql-server

I have a product table and a ProductStockTransactions (SKU, StockingCode, TransactionDate, TransactionQuantity). Every column is required. PST is child table and product is parent table.

A= Add, R= Return, S= sold

Q-- **Return the amount of the product in‐stock** .**

```
SELECT amtInStock = (
            SELECT ISNULL(SUM(T1.transactionQuantity), 0)
            FROM ProductStockTransactions AS T1
            WHERE T1.SKU = Product.SKU
                AND T1.stockingCode IN ('A', 'R')
        ) - (
            SELECT ISNULL(SUM(T1.transactionQuantity), 0)
            FROM ProductStockTransactions AS T1
            WHERE T1.SKU = Product.SKU
                AND T1.stockingCode IN ('S')
        )
```

I am not able to understand why this ISNULL function is used here and I think we will never get a null value here.

I am also confused how this query is executed. Like first we sum all the A or r values and then subtract from total Sold(S) values or one by one taking each value of A or R and then subtracting it and then sum at last. Can anyone explain the code.

Comment: Please note the code formatting button in the question editor `{}`

Comment: You will get NULL when using SUM if you have no rows that meet the where predicates. Therefore using ISNULL here is a good idea. If you didn't have that and **either** sum returned NULL the total would be NULL which is not what you want.

Comment: @SeanLange Wouldn't you get an empty result set in the event that the WHERE predicate didn't hit? So it would be a number or it would be nothing. I'll be honest though, this syntax subtracting two sub-queries is foreign to me, so I'm out of my element.

Comment: @JNevill no. A sum when no rows are returned will return NULL. Try this. select sum(1) from sys.tables where 1 = 0. SUM is an aggregate and will **always** return a row, but it might contain NULL.

Comment: @SeanLange can you please explain the execution of code how it will work.

Comment: It is two subqueries. So it calculates the value of the first one and then subtracts the value of the second one. The parenthesis should guide you on how it works. Not sure if that answers your question or not though.

Comment: I'll be damned. I don't know how I've made it this far in my life without knowing that an aggregate always returns a value. I'm stoked that I learned something this afternoon! Thanks @SeanLange

Comment: @JNevill it makes perfect sense if you think about it. Glad I could share some knowledge. :D

Comment: @SeanLange so it calculated total sum of all the quantities of products with A or R code and then subtract from the total sum of all the quantities of product with S right? Or first it do subtraction of each record then perform sum of teh result.

Comment: It does each subquery on its own. Just like you would expect with parenthesis.

Comment: Thank You very much I just a problem in trigger